# imageview in android doesn't move downward and only expanding horizontally due to which some images are not shown

Tags: android

i have a problem in making android layout
you can see the images of book in the image below. the fourth image of book is resized automatically i need to move it down when the layout is finished

[image: android layout problem]

My code so far is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundmap"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    tools:context="com.example.adeel.freelancerproject.fileexpansion">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fileshelf"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bluebook"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bluebook"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bluebook"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bluebook"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically i need to fix the width of the layout and when finished the rest image is moved downward.
Kindly please help 
Thanks Regards

Comment: Have you considered using a RecyclerView? It seems like you want to make a scrollable list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **GridLayout** and set your desired columns and rows.

You may also use a **FlowLayout** https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout. If the row is filled, next view will go below the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. 
GridLayoutManager accepts spanCount as constructor parameter

```
public GridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
    super(context);
    setSpanCount(spanCount);
}
```

This is how I have used that.

In Activity , lets say PhotoActivity,

```
mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, images);
recycledImageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
recycledImageList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

ImageAdapter is just like other RecyclerView adapters and the photoactivity.xml expects a recyclerView inside.